# Non-Fatal Javascript Error?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I think there's some kind of non-fatal bug in my script that's not allowing me to a/ debug the script with Firebug and b/ causes Firefox to constantly display a Connecting... (with the swirly) while I'm on the page. The script seems to run fine though.

Any ideas what could cause that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlHttp;
var xmlDoc;

loadXMLFile();

function loadXMLFile()
{
    xmlHttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "myFile.xml", true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = StateChange;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function StateChange()
{
    if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 )
    {
        xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        processXML();
    }
}

function processXML()
{
    var firstNames = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("name");
    if (firstNames == null)
    {
        document.write("Oh poo. Query selector returned null.");
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++)
        {
            document.write(firstNames[i].textContent + "<br>");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's bad form to use `document.write()`.

Comment: Using `document.write()` after the page has been parsed is very fatal ; ).

Comment: I'm just trying to get something quick and dirty printed on the page from the XML. Is the script (and thus the `document.write()`) not parsed before the HTML below it? That code lives within `<HEAD></HEAD>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code in your page is parsed, but not executed before the page is completed. This happens, since you're calling `document.write()` from `onreadystatechange` event handler function rather than parsing time.

In this case `document.write()` implicitly calls `document.open()`, which wipes all the code out of the page, and only what is left is the text written by `document.write()`. Also `document` is left open, which causes the browser being "busy". This can be avoided by using `document.close()`, but it won't prevent the original content to vanish.

You need to add an element to the `body` and then use some "real" DOM manipulation method. Something like this:

```
<div id="qResult"></div>
```

Then instead of `document.write()`:

```
document.getElementById('qResult').innerHTML = WHAT_EVER_NEEDED
```

Comment: Thank you! It's great to have an understanding of what's going on, even for poor form functions like `document.write()`.