# array outside a function is allocated space, but a variable outside a function is not allocated in javascript why?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, getelementbyid

this is my javascript code :

```
var strp = [0,19,26,33,40,46,49,57,61,65,67,73,76];
var i = document.getElementById("length").value;
function calculator(){

    document.write("the total cost is " + strp[document.getElementById("length").value]);

     document.write("total is ");
     document.write(strp[i]);   
}
```

i am trying to write a calculating function here. and html part is this:

```
<form>         
    select size   : <select id="length">
                    <option value="0">Please Choose One...</option>
                    <option value="1">10 inches</option>
                    <option value="2">12 inches</option>
      </select>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculator()" />
</form>
```

When i am executing this code in browser, I am accessing array by 'getelementbyid value' and i am getting the correct answer. But when i am storing the getelmentbyid value in a variable , and using the the variable to access the array, the output is undefined why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) wiping out all the previous content of the page. Please use some proper DOM manipulation method like [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) or [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) instead.

Comment: you are write, i just checked it, document.write() is wiping out all the previous content of the page. But why is it doing?

Comment: @user2437762 I've explained it in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14868761/1169519), though it's also explained at the MDN page I linked.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is `i` is undefined because the javascript is rendering before the html. So, when `i` is created, there is no element with id length yet. Try putting the javascript below the html to fix this.

Comment: Hmm... actually you're right with this (+1), though when OP fixes this issue, the one in my answer steps instead...

Comment: but why is array strp defined, but not i? is it some kind of javascript optimization

Comment: `document.getElementById()` returns `undefined` if the element doesn't exist yet. So `i` is undefined because you're assigning `undefined` to it.

Comment: No, its not an optimization. When you create the `strp` variable, it is being assigned to an array that you create, ie `[0,19,26,33,40,46,49,57,61,65,67,73,76]`. When you create the variable `i`, you are assigning it to something that does not exist yet, hence it is undefined. The `strp` variable does not depend on any html.

Comment: yes you are right about it. I just tried this, i wrote another document.write() statement just below the document.write() which i accessed array by getelementbyid, it is not showing anything. why is that?

Comment: document.write("the total cost is " + strp[document.getElementById("length").value]);
 document.write("the total cost is " + strp[document.getElementById("length").value]);                                               the second document.write is not giving any output, why?

Comment: The second write is replacing the first write